# Why does Java code with an inner class generates a third SomeClass$1.class file?

Tags: java, compiler-construction

If I have an inner class, like this:

```
public class Test
{
    public class Inner
    {
        // code ...
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // code ...
    }
}
```

When I compile it, I expect it should generate two files:

```
Test.class
Test$Inner.class
```

So why do I sometimes see classfiles like SomeClass$1.class, even though SomeClass does not contain an inner class called "1"?

Comment: Can you clarify why you did not see Test.class and Test$Inner.class? I assume there another SomeClass in the same package that generated the class files you did see?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The SomeClass$1.class represent anonymous inner class

hava a look at the anonymous inner class section [here](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/javaOO/innerclasses.html)

Comment: Note that the names of inner classes are not specified so they need not be of this form and it would be a bug to rely on that. But that being said, I've not yet seen a compiler that generates different names.

Answer (score 9):

You'll also get something like `SomeClass$1.class` if your class contains a private inner class (not anonymous) but you instantiate it at some point in the parent class.

For example:

```
public class Person {

    private class Brain{
        void ponderLife() {
            System.out.println("The meaning of life is...");
        }
    }

    Person() {
        Brain b = new Brain();
        b.ponderLife();
    }
}
```

This would yield:

```
Person.class
Person$Brain.class
Person$1.class
```

Personally I think that's a bit easier to read than a typical anonymous class especially when implementing a simple interface or an abstract class that only serves to be passed into another local object.

Comment: Why does javac do this? This case is more explicitly asked at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2883181/why-is-an-anonymous-inner-class-containing-nothing-generated-from-this-code

Answer (score 3):

to build up on hhafez : SomeClass$1.class represents anonymous inner classes. 
An example of such a class would be

```
public class Foo{
  public void printMe(){
    System.out.println("redefine me!");
  }
}


public class Bar {
    public void printMe() {
    Foo f = new Foo() {
        public void printMe() {
        System.out.println("defined");
        }
    };
    f.printMe();
    }
}
```

From a normal Main, if you called new Bar().printMe it would print "defined" and in the compilation directory you will find Bar1.class

this section in the above code :

```
    Foo f = new Foo() {
        public void printMe() {
        System.out.println("defined");
        }
    };
```

is called an anonymous inner class.