# NoClassFound in Netbeans 7.3.2, project in wrong context

Tags: java, jackson, netbeans-7, classnotfoundexception

My Netbeans java web project uses BatchFb and thus Jackson. I've included the jars for jackson-mapper-asl and jackson-core-asl.

Unfortunately, I'm not able to run it as I get a **ClassNotFound** exception when I try to initialize an instance of `FacebookBatcher`. It can't find the `VisibilityChecker` class even though I see it in the explorer window. Here's the full stack trace I get:

```java
 ago 11, 2013 12:46:55 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [FacebookServlet] in context with path [/Tesi]      threw exception [Servlet execution threw an exception] with root cause
 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:   org.codehaus.jackson.map.introspect.VisibilityChecker
at   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
at FacebookServlet.doGet(FacebookServlet.java:38)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

I've tried al possible steps: I manually removed the jars from the web-inf/lib folder and put them there again, created a new project from scratch,cleant and build n times, even deleting the netbeans cache didn't help, none of this worked for me.

I inspected the compiled files in the jars and I noticed there's a class named `VisibilityChecker$1.class` in addiction to the regular `VisibilityChecker.class`. I can't open it as there's no source code. I think that this might be the cause, but what can I do now? 
Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**:my project is named Tesi2 and in my context.xml file I have the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context antiJARLocking="true" path="/Tesi2"/>
```

But I just realized in the stack code it references the claspath for another project. ("/Tesi"). I'm quite confused on how to solve this.

Comment: That isn't the problem. `VisibilityChecker$1.class` is an anonymous class used in `VisibilityChecker.class`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [what are the $1 in class file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1075207/what-are-the-1-in-class-file)

Comment: Ok, so what do you suggest to do?

Comment: Check that org.codehaus.jackson.map.introspect.VisibilityChecker actually exists in one of the JARs on the classpath.

Comment: Yes it does exist. It's in the jackson-mapper-asl jar as it should...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, sorry. 
I was referencing an old servlet version. Fixed.