# Android exception description

Tags: java, android, debugging, logging

What does **$1** mean in exceptions like this:

```
Error:[AndroidApp] at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$1.processFileBytes
```

Comment: $1 represents an Anonymous inner class inside Main class... see more about Anonymous classes here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll answer through an example

```
package com.examples;

public class Example {  
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable runner = new Runnable() {          
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println(this.getClass());
            }
        };
        runner.run();
    }
}
```

When you compile the following class in a file `Example.java`

```
javac Example.java
```

you end up with two `.class` files

```
Example.class
Example$1.class
```

And if you run the `main` method, it prints out

```
class com.examples.Example$1
```

This is how the java language generates `.class` files for anonynmous inner classes.

See:

- [what are the $1 in class file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1075207/what-are-the-1-in-class-file)

Answer (score 0):

**this may useful to you                              **

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html