# More .class files generated than existing .java files after compilation

Tags: java, class, build

I was trying to compile a huge open source Java project, and after building it with MAVEN I saw that some folders contain extra classes that didn't exist before in the corresponding folder. In other words, after building the Java project, more .class files are generated in some folders than the .java files that existed before compiling.

Can you explain the reason? Is it normal? What are the practices that lead to such results and change the structure of the project?

Comment: Are you talking about when you get stuff like [filename]$1.class, [filename]$2.class? If so, the question is answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1075207/what-are-the-1-in-class-file).

Comment: Anders Ankan Gardenas is the man. Next time when downvoting, say why. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All nested classes will have their own .class file, resulting in more .class file than .java files.

Comment: Cool! That is what I was searching for. Thank you.