# Why there is more than one byte code class file per java source file?

Tags: java

I have a source java file, Test.java.
While Compiling it, java compiler generates more than one class files as follows (class name suffixed with $ and a unique numerals), 
Test$1.class
Test$2.class
Test$3.class
Test.class
Why such more than one byte code class file per java source file is generated? Is there any limitation on such files in number?

Answer (score 1):

Those are the .class files that hold the anonymous inner classes.

Reference:[what are the $1 in class file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1075207/what-are-the-1-in-class-file)

Comment: Please mark duplicate questions as duplicates rather than answering them.