# Android memory profiler shows 2 activity references why

Tags: android, performance, memory, monitor

I have an android application. I planned to improve the performance of the application by finding critical memory places using android Memory Monitor. I started with my Splash screen Activity.It gives 2 references for the Splash screen along with memory status.I don't know which references i consider, because both the instances having different memory profile.

Here i have added the screen shot of the Splash Screen of my application.

[image]

Steps i followed.(Using MI device)

- Connected My android(Mi) device with android studio over USB cable.
- I started my android application from android menu screen.
- Splash screen is the first activity which has been stared.
- I made Splash screen idle for the time.
- Now i went to "Android Monitor" tab.
- I Switched from "Logcat" tab to "Monitors" tab.
- I Expanded the Memory block i click on "Dump Java Heap" option.
- After some time it opens a .hprof file with the trace view and i switched from "Class List View" to "Package Tree View" android and navigate to my package to look for Splash screen, unfortunately i found two instances of the Splash Screen(highlighted with the red color box in the image above).
- Can any one explain why its showing showing like that.

Answer (score 0):

Splashscreen is your Activity class.

Splashscreen$1 is an anonymous inner class of Splashscreen.

[what are the $1 in class file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1075207/what-are-the-1-in-class-file)