# What does $1 mean in Android Java log, and how to find it?

Tags: java, android

I have this log file in my crash reporter dashboard:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.b()' on a null object reference
       at examplecompany.video.BottomNavActivity$1.onClick(Unknown Source)
       ...
```

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1075224/811785), $1 refers to an inner class. But in my `BottomNavActivity` I have no inner class. Also I can't find `onClick` method in that class. How do I interpret this to find out the problem?

Update: I have a bunch of `setOnClickListener` calls in my code. If it relates to those calls, how do I know which call is the root of the problem, and also why `onClick` is in log file. Why `setOnClickListener` is not logged?

Comment: how about showing some code? probably, you implement ClickListener or the like (or wrote code that expects your class to)

Comment: Presumably it's an anonymous implementation of `OnClickListener`.

Comment: Yeah, I have a bunch of `setOnClickListener` calls. But which one? Also why `onClick`? I don't understand that part.

Comment: i believe u dont have `BottomNavActivity$1` id  in your xml layout

Comment: _"Also why onClick?"_ Because each `OnClickListener` implements `onClick`.