# How many files does the java compiler create? 

Tags: java, javac

If I compile a class

```
class hussi
{
  public static void main(String args[])
  {
    System.out.println("hello java");
  }
}
```

Will I have any file other than hussi.class file?
Does the javac create any file other than .class file ?

Comment: What happens when you try it?

Comment: `javac hussi.java`, <looks at ouput>, <sees 1 class file named hussi.class>.

Comment: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even the package-info.java produces a class.

```
/**
 * Javadoc for a package
 *
 * with an annotation.
 */
@Deprecated
package mypackage;
```

compiled with

```
$ javac package-info.java 
$ ls -l
total 8
-rw-rw-r-- 1 peter peter 180 2012-03-21 12:08 package-info.class
-rw-rw-r-- 1 peter peter  87 2012-03-21 12:08 package-info.java

$ javap -c -v -classpath .. mypackage.package-info
Classfile /d/peter/untitled/src/main/java/mypackage/package-info.class
  Last modified 21-Mar-2012; size 180 bytes
  MD5 checksum f152dc2e8a45929ef297f6ac05a4067e
  Compiled from "package-info.java"
interface mypackage.package-info
  SourceFile: "package-info.java"
  RuntimeVisibleAnnotations:
    0: #6()
  minor version: 0
  major version: 51
  flags: ACC_INTERFACE, ACC_ABSTRACT, ACC_SYNTHETIC
Constant pool:
  #1 = Class              #7              //  "mypackage/package-info"
  #2 = Class              #8              //  java/lang/Object
  #3 = Utf8               SourceFile
  #4 = Utf8               package-info.java
  #5 = Utf8               RuntimeVisibleAnnotations
  #6 = Utf8               Ljava/lang/Deprecated;
  #7 = Utf8               mypackage/package-info
  #8 = Utf8               java/lang/Object
{
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Java compiler creates `.class` for each class. Java file may contain at least 1 class. It can contain more: either top level or inner classes. It can also contain anonymous inner classes. Compiler creates separate file for each such class.

Answer (score 1):

The java compiler produces one file per class, including for inner classes (anonymous or not). They will always be a .class file.

Answer (score 1):

You will get one .class file per class.  If you have inner classes you may end up with multiple .class files per .java file.

Answer (score 1):

Java compiler only create one file that is .class file.

But you must have one public class in a java file to compile this otherwise error will occur,and file name must be same as public class name.

If you have more then one class in a java file then more class file will create.

Answer (score 1):

`javac` will create one `.class` file in this case. However if you have inner classes, along with the class file for the outer class, the class files for inner classes will also be generated

---

Edit: there is a better answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1031966/298455