# How to use files that compiled using scalac command?

Tags: scala, compilation, scalac

I have a file named `Hello.scala` that contains this simple code:

```
object HelloWorld {
    def main(args: Array[String]) {
      println("Hello, world!")
    }
}
```

I compiled it using this command:

```
$ scalac Hello.scala
```

The result was two files named `HelloWorld.class` and `HelloWorld$.class`.
What is these files? How can I use these files?

**Note:** My problem is not duplicate files. I want to know what is this files and how can I execute them?

Thanks for answer

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multiple .class files generated for a class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1031962/multiple-class-files-generated-for-a-class)

Comment: My main problem is that I don't khow how can I use these classes? How to run one of these files and get "Hello, world!"?

Comment: @BoristheSpider First, the link only covers multiple class files for inner classes, not the semantics of scala companion objects and such. Also, that tutorial is out of date as noted, you need http://www.scala-lang.org/documentation/getting-started.html

Comment: @JustinPihony I think the reason for the multiple `.class` files is still the same - multiple classes; but fair enough - Scala generates much random magic. On the updated link - besides the formatting, I don't really see much difference in the tutorial...

Comment: No, but there is always the possibility, so why not point to the up to date reference instead of the one not being updated at all?

Comment: Just a tip: using scalac directly gets to be a huge pain really quickly. Investing in a basic understanding of SBT up front is almost definitely worth it.

Comment: Thanks @BoristheSpider. I get my answer. I could execute HelloWorld.class using your tutorial. :)

Comment: Thanks @JustinPihony for your updated Tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This files are normal **Java Class** / **Bytecode** Files.

You can run them with

```
scala HelloWorld
//Hello, world!
```

Normally you also could run them with

```
java HelloWorld$ // Because it is an object which gets the $ sign at the end
```

But this throws an error as there has to be some wiring done to handle the special case of Object.