# where the class come from?

Tags: class, reflection, javac

jdk:1.8_144
os:debian 9

I compile this class:

```
public class Singleton {
    private static class SingletonHolder {
        private static final SingleTonInner INSTANCE = new SingleTonInner();
    }

    private static class SingleTonInner{
        public void out(){
            System.out.println("SingleTonInner:out");
        }
    }

    private Singleton() {
    }

    public static final SingleTonInner getInstance() {
        return SingletonHolder.INSTANCE;
    }
}
```

But I find 4 .class file on my disk:

```
Singleton$1.class
Singleton.class
Singleton$SingletonHolder.class
Singleton$SingleTonInner.class
```

Here is a class `Singleton$1.class` ? what is it?

I use reflection to get constructor but it has no constructor ! It is nothing!

what is this class and where it come from?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple .class files generated for a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1031962/multiple-class-files-generated-for-a-class)

Comment: Thanks John3136, but I can't find anonymous inner class in my code.

Comment: also mentions static inner classes which you do have.

Comment: I only have 2 static inner classes here Singleton$SingletonHolder.class and 
    Singleton$SingleTonInner.class. And I decompile the Singleton$1.class . There is nothing:
// $FF: synthetic class
class Singleton$1 {
}

Comment: Oh, I get something from synthetic keyword.

Comment: `javap -c /path/to/Singleton$1.class`

Answer (score 1):

#### Original question

Why does the posted code produce a class file named "Singleton$1.class"?
Additionally, you shared that this was found using JDK version 1.8_144.

Here's a simpler version of the original code, which produces the same original behavior:

- class `Singleton`
- static class `SingleTonInner`
- static class `SingletonHolder`

```
public class Singleton {
    private Singleton() { } 
    private static class SingletonInner { } 
    private static class SingletonHolder {
        static { new SingletonInner(); }   
    }   
}
```

What you have encountered is an anonymous inner class – that's the "Singleton$1.class" naming.

From [JLS 15.9.5 - Anonymous Class Declarations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.9.5)

> *An anonymous class declaration is automatically derived from a class instance creation expression by the Java compiler.*

And from [JLS 13.1 - The Form of a Binary](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-13.html#jls-13.1), this is where the "$" number naming is defined:

> *The binary name of a local class ([§14.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.3)) consists of the binary name of its immediately enclosing type, followed by $, followed by a non-empty sequence of digits, followed by the simple name of the local class.*

As you observed, your code doesn't appear to be doing anything obvious to create that anonymous inner class.

#### Observations: JDK 1.8

I was able to reproduce the same thing – generating "Singleton$1.class" – with code posted above
using JDK 1.8.0_341 (latest available version from Oracle).

Here's an attempt with 1.8, first wiping all class files, clearly showing "Singleton$1.class" was created:

```
% rm *.class && javac -version && javac Singleton.java
javac 1.8.0_341

% ls -l
175 Aug  6 18:09 Singleton$1.class
444 Aug  6 18:09 Singleton$SingletonHolder.class
362 Aug  6 18:09 Singleton$SingletonInner.class
352 Aug  6 18:09 Singleton.class
195 Aug  6 18:09 Singleton.java
```

#### Observations: JDK 11 + 17

Here's the same test after switching to JDK 11 – no more "$1.class":

```
% rm *.class && javac -version && javac Singleton.java
javac 11.0.14

% ls -l
413 Aug  6 18:09 Singleton$SingletonHolder.class
289 Aug  6 18:09 Singleton$SingletonInner.class
353 Aug  6 18:09 Singleton.class
195 Aug  6 18:09 Singleton.java
```

Here's the same test with JDK 17, no sign of the anonymous inner class:

```
% rm *.class && javac -version && javac Singleton.java
javac 17.0.1

% ls -l
413 Aug  6 18:09 Singleton$SingletonHolder.class
289 Aug  6 18:09 Singleton$SingletonInner.class
353 Aug  6 18:09 Singleton.class
195 Aug  6 18:09 Singleton.java
```

#### Explanation

I was unable to find a specific reason for this change in behavior, though the evidence must exist.
I suspect this was a bug that was addressed at some
point, and while I'm curious to see the details, my patience got the better of me. ;-)
I did spend time looking through
the Java bug database for various search phrases, including
["anonymous class"](https://www.oracle.com/search/results/_/N-8d?Ntt=anonymous%20class&Dy=1&Nty=1&cat=bugs&Nr=106&Ntk=SI-ALL5)
(currently shows 200+ results), but the search tool is quite bad and page loads are slow.

Without a specific reason, we can still make a few observations about what's going on:

- anonymous classes are a deliberate language feature
- if something worked one way in JDK 1.8, and a different way in JDK 11 (and later), that was either a deliberate change, or a bug – but if it were a bug, it seems reasonable that said bug would have been identified and corrected years ago (and we would continue to see empty anonymous inner classes in recent JDK versions)

The output from [`javap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/specs/man/javap.html) supports the idea that
the change across JDK versions was deliberate:

- the output for the parent class "Singleton" lists a few, normal-looking things:

  ```
  % javap -c -p Singleton.class
  Compiled from "Singleton.java"
  public class Singleton {
    private Singleton();
      Code:
         0: aload_0
         1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
         4: return
  }
  ```
- but the anonymous "Singleton$1" is completely empty:

  ```
  % javap -c -p Singleton\$1.class
  Compiled from "Singleton.java"
  class Singleton$1 {
  }
  ```