# Why is an anonymous inner class containing nothing generated from this code?

Tags: java, inner-classes, anonymous-class

```
package com.test;

public class OuterClass {
    public class InnerClass {
        public class InnerInnerClass {

        }
    }

    public class InnerClass2 {

    }

    //this class should not exist in OuterClass after dummifying
    private class PrivateInnerClass {
        private String getString() {
            return "hello PrivateInnerClass";
        }
    }

    public String getStringFromPrivateInner() {
        return new PrivateInnerClass().getString();
    }
}
```

When run through `javac` on the command line with `Sun JVM 1.6.0_20`, this code produces 6 .class files:

> OuterClass.class
>   OuterClass$1.class
>   OuterClass$InnerClass.class
>   OuterClass$InnerClass2.class
>   OuterClass$InnerClass$InnerInnerClass.class
>   OuterClass$PrivateInnerClass.class

When run through JDT in eclipse, it produces only 5 classes.

> OuterClass.class
>   <del>OuterClass$1.class</del>
>   OuterClass$InnerClass.class
>   OuterClass$InnerClass2.class
>   OuterClass$InnerClass$InnerInnerClass.class
>   OuterClass$PrivateInnerClass.class

When decompiled, `OuterClass$1.class` contains nothing.  Where is this extra class coming from and why is it created?

Comment: I was able to confirm this. `class OuterClass$1 extends java.lang.Object{ }`. Weird.

Comment: does it go away if you make PrivateInnerClass public? Maybe it has something to do with "faking" private access to a class.

Comment: @Alex: no, the bug report from 1999 mentions of dummy class too. See my "answer".

Comment: Thanks all.  I think I'm able to get around my issues based on the various fact-finding missions I sent you all on. :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I don't have the answer, but I'm able to confirm that, and reduce the snippet to the following:

```
public class OuterClass {
    private class PrivateInnerClass {
    }
    public void instantiate() {
        new PrivateInnerClass();
    }
}
```

This creates `OuterClass$1.class`

```
Compiled from "OuterClass.java"
class OuterClass$1 extends java.lang.Object{
}
```

And here's `javap -c` for `OuterClass.class`:

```
Compiled from "OuterClass.java"
public class OuterClass extends java.lang.Object{
public OuterClass();
  Code:
   0:   aload_0
   1:   invokespecial   #1; //Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
   4:   return

public void instantiate();
  Code:
   0:   new     #2; //class OuterClass$PrivateInnerClass
   3:   dup
   4:   aload_0
   5:   aconst_null
   6:   invokespecial #3; //Method OuterClass$PrivateInnerClass."<init>":
                          //(LOuterClass;LOuterClass$1;)V
   9:   pop
   10:  return

}
```

And for `OuterClass$PrivateInnerClass`:

```
Compiled from "OuterClass.java"
class OuterClass$PrivateInnerClass extends java.lang.Object{
final OuterClass this$0;

OuterClass$PrivateInnerClass(OuterClass, OuterClass$1);
  Code:
   0:   aload_0
   1:   aload_1
   2:   invokespecial   #1; //Method "<init>":(LOuterClass;)V
   5:   return

}
```

As you can see, the synthesized constructor takes an `OuterClass$1` argument.

So `javac` creates the default constructor to take an extra argument, of type `$1`, and the value of that default argument is `5: aconst_null`.

---

I've found that `$1` doesn't get created if either of the following is true:

- You make `public class PrivateInnerClass`
- You declare a nullary constructor for `PrivateInnerClass`
- Or you don't call the `new` on it
- Probably other things (e.g. `static` nested, etc).

---

#### Possibly related

- [Bug ID:4295934](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4295934): Compiling a private inner class creates an anonymous class file in the wrong dir

> Create the following source in a directory called test:

> ```
> package test;
> ```

```
public class testClass
{
    private class Inner
    {
    }
    public testClass()
    {
        Inner in = new Inner();
    }
}
```

> Compile the file from the parent directory `javac test/testClass.java`

> Notice that the file `testClass$1.class` is created in the current directory.
> Not sure why this file is even created since there is also a `test/testClass$Inner.class` created as well.

> **EVALUATION**

> The `testClass$1.class` file is for a dummy class needed by an "access
> constructor" for the private constructor of the private inner class
> `testClass$Inner`.   Dissassembly shows that the fully-qualified name of
> this class is correctly noted, so it is unclear why the class file ends
> up in the wrong directory.

Comment: When the same class is run via Eclipse, the empty class(OuterClass$1.class) is not getting created. Any idea

Answer (score 26):

I'm using polygenelubricants's smaller snippet.

Remember there's no concept of nested classes in the bytecode; the bytecode is, however, aware of access modifiers. The problem the compiler is trying to circumvent here is that
**the method `instantiate()` needs to create a new instance of `PrivateInnerClass`. However, `OuterClass` does not have access to `PrivateInnerClass`'s constructor** (`OuterClass$PrivateInnerClass` will be generated as a package-protected class without a public constructor).

So what can the compiler do? The obvious solution is to change `PrivateInnerClass` to have a package-protected constructor. The problem here is that this will allow any other code which interfaces with the class to create a new instance of `PrivateInnerClass`, even though it's explicitly declared as private!

To try and prevent that, the javac compiler is doing a little trick: instead of making `PrivateInnerClass`'s regular constructor visible from other classes, it leaves it as hidden (actually it does not define it at all, but that's the same thing from outside). Instead, it creates a new constructor which receives an additional parameter of the special type `OuterClass$1`.

Now, if you look at `instantiate()`, it calls that new constructor. It actually sends `null` as the 2nd parameter (of the type `OuterClass$1`) - that parameter is only used for specifying that this constructor is the one that should be called.

So, why create a new type for the 2nd parameter? Why not use, say, `Object`? It's only used to differentiate it from the regular constructor and `null` is passed anyway! And the answer is that as `OuterClass$1` is private to OuterClass, a legal compiler will never allow the user to invoke the special `OuterClass$PrivateInnerClass` constructor, as one of the required parameter types, `OuterClass$1`, is hidden.

I'm guessing JDT's compiler uses another technique to solve the same problem.

Comment: and OP: if my smaller snippet is an easier subject of discussion, feel free to hoist it into the question instead (since my "answer" is more of a fact finding mission appropriate for a question anyway).

Answer (score 7):

Based on the answer of polygenelubricants, I would guess that this mysterious class prevents anybody else (i.e., outside from `OuterClass`) from instantiating a `OuterClass$PrivateInnerClass`, because they don't have access to `OuterClass$1`.

Comment: Man, it took me 22 lines to give the same answer. You rock :)

Answer (score 4):

After searching I found this link. http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6378717

Comment is referring to source code that is available in given link.

> This is not a bug.
>
> The compiler is trying to solve an access problem.  Since the inner
>   class Test.Request is private its constructor is private. This can be
>   seen if you use -private to javap:
>
> $ javap -private Test\$Request Compiled from "Test.java" final class
>   Test$Request extends java.lang.Object{
>       final Test this$0;
>       private Test$Request(Test);
>       Test$Request(Test, Test$1); }
>
> However, the JVM will not allow the anonymous subclass of Coucou
>   (Test$1) access to this private constructor.  This is a fundamental
>   difference between the JVM and the Java programming language when it
>   comes to nested classes.  The language allows nested classes to access
>   private members of the enclosing class.
>
> Originally, when nested classes were added to the language, the
>   solution to this problem was to make the constructor package private
>   and would have looked like this:
>
> $ javap -private Test\$Request Compiled from "Test.java" final class
>   Test$Request extends java.lang.Object{
>       final Test this$0;
>       Test$Request(Test); }
>
> However, this can easily lead to problems where you can get access to
>   the constructor when you shouldn't.  To address this problem, the
>   current solution was invented.  The "real" constructor will remain
>   private:
>
> ```
> private Test$Request(Test);
> ```
>
> However, other nested classes must be allowed to call this
>   constructor. So an access constructor must be provided.  However, this
>   access constructor must be different from the "real" constructor.  To
>   solve this problem the compiler adds an extra parameter to the access
>   constructor.  The type of this extra parameter must be something
>   unique that doesn't conflict with anything the user might have
>   written.  So an obvious solution is to add an anonymous class and use
>   that as the type of the second parameter:
>
> ```
> Test$Request(Test, Test$1);
> ```
>
> However, the compiler is clever and reuses any anonymous class if one
>   exists.  If you change the example to not include an anonymous class,
>   you will see that the compiler will create one:
>
> public abstract class Test {
>       private final class Request {}
>       private final class OtherRequest {    Request test() { return new Request(); }
>       } }
>
> If there is no access to the private constructor, the compiler doesn't
>   need to generate any access constructor which explains the behavior of
>   this example:
>
> public abstract class Test {
>       private final class Request {} }

Answer (score 0):

One more spot - if `OuterClass$1` is already declared by user, `OuterClass$PrivateInnerClass` will have it as a constructor argument anyways:

```
public class OuterClass { 

    ... 

    public String getStringFromPrivateInner() { 
        PrivateInnerClass c = new PrivateInnerClass();
        Object o = new Object() {};
        return null;
    }
}
```

-

```
public java.lang.String getStringFromPrivateInner();
  Code:
   0:   new     #2; //class OuterClass$PrivateInnerClass
   3:   dup
   4:   aload_0
   5:   aconst_null
   6:   invokespecial   #3; //Method OuterClass$PrivateInnerClass."":
(LOuterClass;LOuterClass$1;)V
   9:   astore_1
   10:  new     #4; //class OuterClass$1
   13:  dup
   14:  aload_0
   15:  invokespecial   #5; //Method OuterClass$1."":(LOuterClass;)V
   18:  astore_2
   19:  aconst_null
   20:  areturn
```