# When compiling codes with inner class, why the strange output file is created?

Tags: java, inner-classes

I compiled this code and then, `TestInner$1.class` emerged.

I know `~~~$1.class` indicates that file has "*anonymous class.*"

But I don't understand the reason why this class file made. I want to know the reason.

Here is the code.

```
public class TestInner {
    private static class Inner { }

    public static void main(String[] args){
         new Inner();
    }
}
```

I tried another version removed "*private*" identifier, like the following.

```
public class TestInner {
    static class Inner { }

    public static void main(String[] args){
         new Inner();
    }
}
```

I'd imagined that this code also would make `TestInner$1.class` file.

However it didn't create the file.

In addition, the following code, added *Constructor*, also didn't make `TestInner$1.class`.

```
public class TestInner {
    private static class Inner {
        Inner(){ }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
         new Inner();
    }
}
```

I have no idea, so can anyone help me?

**EDIT**:

I found the same question and it solved. Thank you for your helping.

[Why is an anonymous inner class containing nothing generated from this code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2883181/why-is-an-anonymous-inner-class-containing-nothing-generated-from-this-code)

Comment: You do not have any anonymous classes in your samples.

Comment: All of your samples should be creating a `TestInner$Inner.class`. Nothing should be generating `TestInner$1.class`. Perhaps it is left over from previous experiments.

Comment: You may want to work through [Anonymous Classes tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html).

Comment: Are you sure that you haven't used something like `new Inner(){};` by mistake?

Comment: I do know that this code doesn't include any "anonymous class." But indeed it emerged. And "new Inner();" is not mistaken.

Comment: And if you doubt me, Please try to compile this code.

Comment: @user3161279 I did compile the code. I compiled all three of your snippets (it's the first thing I did). As expected, `TestInner$Inner.class` was produced in all 3 cases, and `TestInner$1.class` was never produced. What compiler are you using and what platform are you on?

Comment: @Jason C Thanks a lot for your trying. I use 1.7.0_25 and Windows7. My colleague also try on 1.7.0_45 and Windows7 but he got `TestInner$1.class`, either.

Comment: I googled and then get the info "if you use Eclipse, this class file is not created."

Comment: @user3161279 Huh. Yes, I can confirm that *without* using Eclipse I get `TestInner$1.class` for your first example but not for the last two, just like you are seeing. I will have to do some more research.

Comment: @Jason C Thank you! I'll research again, too.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is an anonymous inner class containing nothing generated from this code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2883181/why-is-an-anonymous-inner-class-containing-nothing-generated-from-this-code) (as per OPs edit to question)

Comment: @user3161279 Good find!

Answer (score 4):

None of your examples have anonymous inner classes. None of them will produce a file named `TestInner$1.class`. All of them will produce a file named `TestInner$Inner.class`.

The following example shows an anonymous inner class and *will* produce `TestInner$1.class`:

```
public class TestInner {
    public static void main(String[] args){
         new Object() {
             @Override public String toString () {
                 return "ninja";
             }
         };
    }
}
```

I'm not sure where your `TestInner$1.class` came from but I'm guessing it's left over from previous experiments you were doing.

---

Update 1: I can confirm that *without* using Eclipse I get `TestInner$1.class` (in addition to `TestInner$Inner.class` -- 3 files are produced) for the first example but not for the last two, just like you are seeing. Will update when I find out why. When compiled via Eclipse, `TestInner$1.class` is never produced.

---

Update 2: OP found solution in [Why is an anonymous inner class containing nothing generated from this code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2883181/why-is-an-anonymous-inner-class-containing-nothing-generated-from-this-code?lq=1).

Comment: It is impossible the file was left over absolutely. Because I'd deleted the files, TestInner*.class, and verified whether those files was really removed  or not. Then I tried compiling again and again.