# Why does compiling a class containing static nested classes create a new .class file named "EnclosingClass$1"?

Tags: java, javac, nested-class, .class-file

In the below code :

```
 class EnclosingClass
 { 
     public static class BiNode extends Sub.IBiLink { }
     private static class Sub
     {
         private static class IBiLink
         {  
         } 
     }
}
```

On compiling along with other .class files, I also see a file named "EnclosingClass$1.class" .Why has this been automatically created? Whats going on?

Comment: All the inner classes defined here are static

Comment: The Eclipse compiler doesn't generate such a class file. `javac 1.8.0_20` does. There is no requirement for such a .class file according to the spec afaik. It may make things easier for javac.

Comment: When `IBiLink` is declared as package-local, no `Enclosing$1` is generated, although I don't understand why.

Comment: The class signature you describe is for an anonymous inner class.

Comment: Interesting question. I couldn't figure it out either, but after some testing, I did notice that EnclosingClass$1.class is only generated when IBiLink is private.

Comment: @vsnyc Nice find.  The second (and highest voted) answer in that thread is even more satisfying, as Oak seems to have a plausible answer.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/2883541/312407

Comment: This can't be closed as duplicate while the bounty is open though.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis What is the version of the build path on your eclipse ?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisSavard Do you mean the Compiler Compliance Level? 1.8

Answer (score 5):

First have a look at the class access and propery modifier table from the JVM specifications.

[image]

Notice the `ACC_SYNTHETIC` flag which interpretation specify that it is not present in the source code (in simplier words, it will be added when the class is generated by the compiler).

---

Let's have a look at the bytecode of `EnclosingClass$1.class` (note that I will paste only the part that matter).

```
javap -v EnclosingClass$1.class
```

produce the following result

```
Classfile /C:/Users/jfrancoiss/Desktop/Nouveau dossier/EnclosingClass$1.class
  Last modified 2015-03-31; size 190 bytes
  MD5 checksum 5875440f1e7f5ea9a519d02fbec6dc8f
  Compiled from "EnclosingClass.java"
class EnclosingClass$1
  minor version: 0
  major version: 52
  flags: ACC_SUPER, ACC_SYNTHETIC
```

Notice that the access flags of the class contains `ACC_SYNTHETIC`.

> The ACC_SYNTHETIC flag indicates that this class or interface was
>   generated by a compiler and does not appear in source code.

An other option to make sure the generated class is synthetic is to compile as

```
javac -XD-printflat EnclosingClass.java
```

which would produce

```
/*synthetic*/ class EnclosingClass$1 {
}
```

---

Great, but why generate a synthetic class ?

The Java reflection tutorial can help us understand this. Have a look at the comments in the [`SyntheticConstructor`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/example/SyntheticConstructor.java) class

```
public class SyntheticConstructor {
    private SyntheticConstructor() {}
    class Inner {
    // Compiler will generate a synthetic constructor since
    // SyntheticConstructor() is private.
    Inner() { new SyntheticConstructor(); }
    }
}
```

So according on the comment, the synthetic class `EnclosingClass$1.class` was created because `IBiLink` was private.

Once again, the [java reflection tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/ctorModifiers.html) specify at this point

> Since the inner class's constructor references the private constructor
>   of the enclosing class, the compiler must generate a package-private
>   constructor.

In our case, we do not see explicitely any constructor call, but we have this line

```
public static class BiNode extends Sub.IBiLink { }
```

Let's try compiling this code and see what happen

```
class EnclosingClass
 { 
     //public static class BiNode extends Sub.IBiLink { }
     private static class Sub
     {
         private static class IBiLink
         {  
         } 
     }
}
```

No `EnclosingClass$1.class` generated.

---

**More details noticed when debugging**

Change

```
private static class IBiLink
```

to

```
protected static class IBiLink
```

notice that when compiling, `EnclosingClass$1.class` is not created.

why does protecting the class did not generate a synthetic class ?

Simply because when protecting the class, you implicitely get access to each of the super classes.

---

**Why don't eclipse compiler generate a synthetic class ?**

Eclipse use it built-in compiler, which you can configure it severity level.

By default, *Access to a non-accessible member of an enclosing type* is set to *ignore* as you can see on this image.

[image]

Change it for example to *warning* and you will get the following message.

[image]

which let me believe that eclipse, altought does not create an other class, will emulate it to simulate the synthetic member.