# What is the name of "${}" and where can I find documentation on them for NetBeans IDE?

Tags: java, netbeans

I just started using the NetBeans IDE and in poking around i have seen ${*some code here*} (e.g. `${user}` or `${package}`), especially in templates, seemingly as a manner of pulling information from another source.

I do not know what the terminology is for these, the closest I can find are code hints or code templates but those do not seem to be the same as these. Because I do not know what to call them, I do not know how to find more information on them. Specifically I want a list of all of these "shortcodes" supported by or built into the NetBeans IDE and what they "point" to.

Comment: http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqTemplateVariables

Comment: They appear to be template makers/variables, which are replaced when the template is used to create a document.  I think WillShackleford provided a useful link for more details

Comment: willshackleford can you put that into an answer so i can accept it? that is exactly what i was looking for. thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Credit for this answer goes to WillShackleford. He posted the link in a comment which allowed me to get all the information I was looking for.

They are called template variables. They are part of the implementation of the FreeMarker Template Language, specifically they are Interpolations, in the NetBeans IDE.

Information about them can be found at:
http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqTemplateVariables
http://freemarker.org/docs/dgui_template_valueinsertion.html

General information regarding the FreeMarker Template Language and its use in the NetBeans IDE can also be found at the above links.

Answer (score -2):

The dollar sign is related to the anonymous inner class. You can check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2883315/1691980)

Comment: Not in this context, they are (I believe) template marks.  Unless you're going to expand on the links, you should either mark the question as a duplicate or leave it as comment, otherwise you simply riding the back of other peoples success/hard work ;)